# Formatting Dates in Code to British format

Tags: c#, date, format

Good morning, please see code below, is there a way that I can get c# to accept the date in UK date format?

```
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime myValue = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime myBirthday = DateTime.Parse("1977, 3, 30");
            TimeSpan myAge = DateTime.Now.Subtract(myBirthday);
            Console.WriteLine (myAge.TotalDays);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In what was is `yyyy, M, d` a UK date format? Normally that's `d/M/yyyy`. But yes, you can easily parse that format - look at `DateTime.ParseExact`.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse via culture:

```
var culture = "en-GB";
var date = DateTime.Parse(dateString, new CultureInfo(culture , false));
```

But that would be down to .NETs interpretation of a UK date format, but you may ot match that so it may be better to do it based on your data, e.g.:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code with **CultureInfo**:

```
var str = "01/01/2016 00:00:00";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
var res = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

in res u have your date in British Format.

Comment: @mrpjspencer can u approve my answer ?